# If I am going for a second masters and my previous GRE score is expired, do I have to take the GRE again?

Tags: gre, second-degree

I am already done with my masters but I want to go back to school for another one. The only thing is that I got my masters 9 years ago. I know GRE is only valid for 5 years. Since I already done with one masters, would I be required to take the GRE again if I want to go for another one?

Comment: FYI, I applied to do a masters in British Columbia. When I submitted my application, my GRE scores were 4 years and 11 months old. They sat on the application a month, then said it was incomplete as my GRE scores were too old. They kept my $150 application fee, of course! The lesson is that your application some times has to get past administrators before it gets considered, and some of these administrators can be particularly unforgiving.

Comment: I actually had a same problem, I have a master and wanted to apply for PhD, Calgary told me I should apply and request for a waiver, as their admission committee does not grant waivers! I told them I can't apply and pay the application fee and only hope to see that maybe it will be waived. In fact, it was their fault not to consider the point of a GRE subject test. GRE is a necessity for an undergrad who wants to pursue a graduate program, not a person with a master willing to do a related PhD. Calgary didn't pay attention to this difference here, and I didn't risk.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.

I applied to a top department at an RU/VH university in the United States, and asked to have the GRE requirement waived for exactly the same reason, and they waived the requirement, and then admitted me to the program.

**Ask the admissions office/committee if they will wave the requirement.**

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.  If you want to apply for another masters degree you have to submit a full application (with in-date GRE scores).  If you have maintained a close relationship with the university, you may be able to wiggle out of the GRE requirement, but that is because the faculty already know your work.

It won't hurt to ask.  You should contact the admissions office and explain your circumstance.  If the university is local, it might be worth showing up in person.  Be polite, and be ready to have to re-study and re-take the GRE though.